# Character varieties of finitely generated groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, character-varieties

Consider the following situation: $\Gamma_0\leq\Gamma$ are both finitely generated groups and $\Gamma_0$ has finite index in $\Gamma$. The restriction gives a well defined map between the character varieties of these groups:
$$\mathrm{Res}:M(\Gamma,\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C}))\longrightarrow M(\Gamma_0,\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C}))$$
where $M(\Gamma,\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C}))$ is the GIT quotient of the variety $\mathrm{Hom}(\Gamma,\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C}))$ under the action of $\mathrm{GL}_N(\mathbb{C})$ by conjugation. Is it always true that the map $\mathrm{Res}$ is proper ? If not, can you provide a (simple) counterexample ?

Tanks in advance. Benoît

Comment: Free groups of different ranks?

Comment: By proper do you mean that preimage of every compact is compact? Then the answer is yes. 

Comment: Bienvenu mon cher Ben !

Comment: If $\mathbb{F}_m\leq\mathbb{F}_n$ with finite index, $m$ is greater than $n$ and the dimensions of mduli spaces increase (it is not an obstruction to properness). Do you try to do some computations on this example ?

Comment: Misha- How do you prove this ?

Comment: If a group acts on a Euclidean building and a finite-index subgroup fixes a point then the original group also fixes a point. 
To see this note that a group fixes a point iff it has a bounded orbit. The reduction of your question to buildings goes through compactification of char. varieties by group actions on buildings worked out by Ann Parreau in her thesis. 

Comment: Misha - this should be an answer!

Comment: Dear Benoit, Perhaps I'm confused (I'm not used to working with character varieties in precisely your set-up, but rather in the related, but technically slightly different, contexts), but won't the map even be *finite* (in the sense of algebraic geometry), i.e. proper with finite fibres.  Concretely, given an $n$-dimensional rep'n of $\Gamma_0$, won't there be at most finitely many non-isomorphic ways to extend it to an $n$-dimensional representation of $\Gamma$ if the index $[\Gamma:\Gamma_0]$ is finite?  Regards, 

Comment: @Emerton: Consider the map $(x,y)\to x$ restricted to the hyperbola $xy=1$. This map is a finite morphism but is not proper (in the sense of point-set topology) as a map from the hyperbola to the $x$-axis. 

Comment: @Misha: no, the projection of the hyperbola is not a finite morphism in the sense of algebraic geometry ($K[t,t^{-1}]$ is not a finitely generated module over $K[t]$). Finite includes proper in the definition.

Comment: @Yves, you are right, I confused finite and quasi-finite. However, observation that fibers of $Res$ are finite only proves that $Res$ is quasi-finite, so it does not help with proving properness of the restriction map. 

Comment: @Misha: sure. But since you proved the restriction map is proper on complex points, it is a proper morphism and since it's quasi-finite, it is a finite morphism. It would be tempting to give a direct proof of this fact. By the way, is the restriction map $Hom(\Gamma,G)\to Hom(\Gamma_0,G)$ always proper (before taking GIT quotients)?

Comment: @Yves: Yes, I noticed this too, maybe this was the point of Emerton's comment. Concerning a direct algebro-geometric proof of finiteness,  I almost see how to do it: Every character of every cyclic subgroup of $\Gamma_0$ has only (uniformly) finite number of extensions to a character of a larger cyclic subgroup of $\Gamma$, this should be enough when the target group $G$ is $GL(n,C)$ since finite number of characters determine affine embedding of the $GL(n,C)$ character variety. Concerning your last question, the answer is no, say, for $\Gamma_0=1$ and $\Gamma$ finite... 

Comment: ...However, it is probably true if you restrict to Zariski dense representations (I checked that this works in rank 1 case). 

Comment: @Misha: indeed! I was not careful. I also realized it fails in $SL_2$ when $\Gamma=\mathbf{Z}$ and $\Gamma_0$ has index 2: the image is not even closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Claim. The restriction map is always proper, where the target group $G$ is the group of $K$-points of a reductive group over a local field $K$, e.g. $G=GL_N({\mathbb C})$.

Proof. First, some generalities, details for which you can find, for instance, [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.1111). Let $X$ be the symmetric space or a locally compact Euclidean building corresponding to $G$. For each representation $\rho$ to $G$ of a group $\Lambda$ with generators $\gamma_1,...,\gamma_k$, define the min-max displacement
$$
d_\rho:=\inf_{x\in X} d_\rho(x), d_\rho(x):=\max_j \rho(\gamma_j)(x).
$$ 
Let $x_\rho\in X$ denote a point for which $d_\rho(x)-d_\rho\le 1$. It is not hard to check that the number $d_\rho$ depends only on the projection $[\rho]$ of $\rho$ to $M(\Lambda, G)$. Furthermore, a sequence $[\rho_i]$ is precompact in $M(\Lambda, G)$ iff the sequence $(d_{\rho_i})$ is bounded. Suppose that $[\rho_i]$ is not precompact and the sequence $(d_{\rho_i})$ diverges to infinity. Then you take the asymptotic cone $Cone(X)$ of $X$ centered at the points $x_{\rho_i}$ with scaling factors $(d_{\rho_i})^{-1}$. The result is an isometric action $\rho$ of $\Lambda$ on $Cone(X)$ without a common fixed point. The key fact is that $Cone(X)$ is a Euclidean building, by a theorem of Kleiner and Leeb. By the Cartan-Tits theorem, the action $\rho$ has no bounded orbits.

Now, we can prove the claim. Suppose to the contrary, that there exists a sequence of representations $\rho_i$ of $\Gamma$ whose projections to $M=M(\Gamma, G)$ diverge, while their restrictions $\rho'_i$ to $\Gamma_0$ project to a relatively compact sequence in $M(\Gamma_0,G)$. Then the above construction yields an action $\rho$ of $\Gamma$ on $Cone(X)$.

Note that the restricted actions $\rho_i'$ have bounded $d_{\rho'_i}$. There are two cases to consider:

1. The distance between points $x_{\rho_i'}$ and $x_{\rho_i}$ is $O(d_{\rho_i})$. Then 
   the sequence  $(x_{\rho_i'})$ represents a point $x$ in $Cone(X)$. This point is necessarily fixed by $\Gamma_0$. Thus, since $|\Gamma:\Gamma_0|<\infty$, the $\Gamma$-orbit of $x$ is bounded, which is a contradiction.
2. $d_{\rho_i}=o(d(x_{\rho_i'},x_{\rho_i}))$. Then geodesic segments between $x_{\rho_i'},x_{\rho_i}$ represent a geodesic ray in $Cone(X)$. The point at infinity $\xi$ represented by this ray is fixed by $\Gamma_0$ and, moreover, every element of $\Gamma_0$ acts as a unipotent isometry of $Cone(X)$. Hence, $\Gamma_0$ has a common fixed point in $X$. Now, the argument is the same as in Case 1. QED.

Comment: Many thanks for your precise answer Misha. Bests